# Sharepoint 2010 filter custom list using user login

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Hi sharepoint experts,

Can somebody help me with this pls.

For sharepoint 2010

I want to filter my custom list based on user who login, I want to use out of the box of sharepoint or view and no coding pls.

```
Name    Position    ID  Manager Supervisor
AA      Manager     1       
BB      Manager     2       
CC      Supervisor  3     AA    
DD      Supervisor  4     BB    
EE      Resource    5     AA        CC
FF      Resource    6     BB        DD
```

> **Manager login

If A A login, he can see records for CC and  EE and if BB, he can see records for DD and FF

> **Supervisor Login

IF CC login , he can see record for EE and if DD he can see record of FF

> **Resource Login

Resource can only see his record.

Answer (score 0):

Add people/group picker columns to your list for Manager and Supervisor (and Position, if that's what you mean it to be). Create a workflow that runs on item creation and modification. Make an impersonation step, and be sure that the workflow is published by someone who has the ability to set permissions in the list. Use the workflow action "Replace List Item Permissions" to set permissions only for IT admins, service accounts (look to parent site permissions for clues on who to include), Created By, and people in the Manager and Supervisor (and Position) columns.